# Return BIGINT[] FROM postgresql function

Tags: arrays, postgresql, function

I know that some similar questions have been asked before but none of the answers worked for me!
I use POSTGRESQL 8.4 and am trying to return an array of BIGINT values from a function. 
My query looks like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.bigint_func(
    in "in_arg" BIGINT)
  RETURNS SETOF BIGINT
  AS
$body$
DECLARE bigint_list BIGINT [ ];
BEGIN
      SELECT
        id
      FROM
        table1
    INTO bigint_list;
  RETURN NEXT;
  END
$body$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
  VOLATILE
  CALLED ON NULL INPUT
  SECURITY INVOKER;
```

and I'd like to use that function as below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
table1 
JOIN (SELECT ids
  FROM bigint_func(123))t2 ON table1.id = t2.id
```

but I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
```

How should I write the code for the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you might be blending two ways of doing what you are trying to accomplish.  Either loop through and return a value at a time, or return everything as a query.

I think either of these will work.

Loop and return a row at a time.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bigint_func(
    in "in_arg" BIGINT)
  RETURNS SETOF BIGINT
  AS
$body$
DECLARE
 bigint_list BIGINT [ ];
 my_id bigint;
BEGIN
  for my_id in
      SELECT
        id
      FROM
        table1 
  loop
    RETURN NEXT my_id;
  END loop;
end;
$body$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
  VOLATILE
```

Or return the entire query as a dataset.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bigint_func(
    in "in_arg" BIGINT)
  RETURNS SETOF BIGINT
  AS
$body$
DECLARE
 bigint_list BIGINT [ ];
BEGIN
  return query
      SELECT
        id
      FROM
        table1;
end;
$body$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
  VOLATILE
```

-- EDIT --

To get the query working, maybe change the return type to a table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bigint_func(in "in_arg" BIGINT)
RETURNS table (id bigint)
  AS
$body$
BEGIN
  return query
    SELECT
      table1.id
    FROM
      table1;
end;
$body$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
  VOLATILE;
```

Then you can name the field anything you want (id in this case)

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  table1 
  join bigint_func(123) t2
    ON table1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: The function is fine now but I'm having problem with joining; when I use this query SELECT * 
FROM 
table1 
JOIN (SELECT id
  FROM bigint_func(123))t2 ON table1.id = t2.id I get the error that t2.id is not known!

Comment: Hmm...  I see what you mean.  Maybe there is a way to alias the output, but if not, you can declare the return type as a table (or `setof`)